# Interpolate string by reading the key and value pair from record using Ballerina

Tags: ballerina

```
function interpolateMessage(string msgTemp, *record{||} values) returns string
```

I need to implement a Ballerina function that replaces the values in the `msgTemp` string by reading the key and value pair from the `values` record.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a regex expression to find and replace the values in a string as shown below.

```
import ballerina/io;

type Options record {
    string value = "a";
    int min = 2;
    int max = 10;
};

function interpolateMessage(string msgTemp, *Options values) returns string {
    string msg = msgTemp;
    foreach var [k, v] in values.entries() {
        msg = re `\{${k}\}`.replaceAll(msg, v.toString());
    }
    return msg;
}

public function main() {
    string msgTemp = "The user name: '{value}' must be between {min} and {max} characters long";
    string interpolatedMsg = interpolateMessage(msgTemp, value = "Foo");
    io:println(interpolatedMsg);
}
```